# Decreasing the margins of Rstudio plots

Tags: plot, statistics, rstudio

I'm conducting a meta-analysis in RStudio, and the margins of the plot are too big. How do I reduce the size of the margins so that the plot fits inside the window?

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: I'm just using the forest function in the metafor package to plot my results. I'm not using any parameters that deal with the width or height of the plot.

Comment: Why don't you just change the `mar` argument in the `par` function.
e.g. `par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,2.1)` would respectively change the margins on the bottom, left, top, and right.